# Error in rep(" ", spaces1) : invalid 'times' argument

Tags: r

I'm trying to carry out covariate balancing using the ebal package. The basic code is:

```
W1 <- weightit(Conformidad ~ SexoCon + DurPetFiscPrisión1 +
                Edad + HojaHistPen + NacionCon + AnteVivos +
                TipoAbog + Reincidencia + Habitualidad + Delitos,
                data = Suspension1,
                method = "ebal", estimand = "ATT")
```

I then want to check the balance using the summary function:

`summary(W1)`

This originally worked fine but now I get the error message:

Error in rep(" ", spaces1) : invalid 'times' argument

It's the same dataset and same code, except I changed some of the covariates. But now even when I go back to original covariates I get the same error. Any ideas would be very appreciated!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of `WeightIt`. That looks like a bug. I'll take a look at it. Are you using the most updated version of `WeightIt`?

Also, `summary()` doesn't assess balance. To do that, you need to use `cobalt::bal.tab()`. `summary()` summarizes the distribution of the weights, which is less critical than examining balance. `bal.tab()` displays the effect sample size as well, which is probably the most important statistic produced by `summary()`.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error message. This happens when the treatment variable is coded as factor or character, but not as numeric in `weightit`.
To make `summary()` work, you need to use 1 and 0.